# Is it possible to load from a .HTML file with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
function loadAjax(filename){
    var ajax;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
            document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET",filename,true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

If `filename` is a `.txt` file, this works as expected. However, if it is a `.html` file, no response is shown.

Comment: what response do you expect...?

Comment: The XMLHTTPRequest object does not care if the URL to fetch ends with a .txt or an .html

What is likely happening is that the ajax.responseText is invalid HTML which causes a problem when you try to add it to your document.

Add a printout of ajax.responseText to verify

Comment: Hot f12 in ie or chrome and look in the console. HTML should be well formed XML

Answer (score 4):

The answer is of course yes, but I would suggest using JQuery's `load` function as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). It is just so much easier to use an abstraction rather than mess with the low-level details of the XHR and the DOM.

This assumes your HTML is valid.

In your case, the code would be something like `$("#target").load(filename);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes its Possible Use JQuery load

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#urButton").click(function() {
    $("#urDiv").load("trackingCode.html");
    });
   });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<button id="urButton">Click Me</button>
<div id="urDiv"></div>
```